# Use variables to set ranges of columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following piece of VBA code:

```
Dim lCol As Variant
Dim nCol As Variant

lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
nCol = lCol + 1
Columns(lCol).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns(), Type:=xlFillDefault
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

In Columns I would like to define a range from lCol to nCol which will be changeable as the code is part of the report which will be with every date, starting from left to right.

Thank you in advance.
Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, this code sample accomplishes your goal simply by **converting column numbers to letters**.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range
    
    Dim lCol As Integer
    Dim nCol As Integer
    Dim LeftColLetter As String
    Dim RightColLetter As String
    
    lCol = 3   'you would change this as-needed, or send in as parameter
    nCol = 5   'you would change this as-needed, or send in as parameter
    
    'first, get the letters of the column
    LeftColLetter = Split(Cells(1, lCol).Address, "$")(1)
    RightColLetter = Split(Cells(1, lCol + (nCol - 1)).Address, "$")(1)

    Set rng = Range(LeftColLetter & ":" & RightColLetter)
    
    Debug.Print rng.Columns.Count   'a quick sanity-check of the result - 5, in this case

'All of your manipulations (inserts, fills, etc.) would go here, based on the above range
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The possibility to return an integer to string is a good idea but after implementation, I still get an error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error."
After defining which is the last column the code looks like: 
    LeftColLetter = Split(Cells(1, lCol).Address, "$")(1)
    RightColLetter = Split(Cells(1, nCol).Address, "$")(1)

    Set rng = Range(LeftColLetter & ":" & RightColLetter)
    Columns(lCol).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns(lCol & ":" & nCol), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

End Sub

Comment: I have seen that often and it is usually resolved by fully qualifying your range references with the sheet name.

Comment: So, try... Set rng = Sheets("sheet name here").Range(LeftColLetter & ":" & RightColLetter)

Comment: And the range in Columns parenthesis should be defined as Columns(range)? If so, it does not work again :(

Comment: Have you tried accessing Range.Columns instead of Columns(Range)?